# Jquery multistep form easing issue sections on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day guys, i just implemented a jquery multistep form on a site i am working on, it works the way it should but causes the elements on the page to loose their original position after clicking the previous button on the form, what could be casuing it? [thats what the form looks like before clicking the previous button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEUL5.jpg)

[thats what the page looks like after clicking previous button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSUfG.jpg)

Comment: Good day to you too, user. Do you expect us to guess what your code looks like?

Comment: i am sorry about that, would be updating it now. thanks